# jquery notification on page load, not onclick

Tags: jquery, notifications

I want to display jquery notifications, but at the moment it is fired onclick. I want on page load. I can see a function: `onclick="return showSuccessMessage()`. Tried to change to onload, but it didnt help. Any ideas??

The code:

HMTL with internal javascript:

```
<div class="container">


                        Demo: <input type="button" class="button" value="Show Success Message" onclick="return showSuccessMessage()"/>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function showSuccessMessage(){
                                showNotification({
                                    type : "success",
                                    message: "This is a sample success notification"
                                });    
                            }                                
                        </script>
                    </li>

    </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
/**
 * Javascript functions to show top nitification
 * Error/Success/Info/Warning messages
 * Developed By: Ravi Tamada
 * url: http://androidhive.info
 * © androidhive.info
 * 
 * Created On: 10/4/2011
 * version 1.0
 * 
 * Usage: call this function with params 
 showNotification(params);
 **/

function showNotification(params){
    // options array
    var options = { 
        'showAfter': 0, // number of sec to wait after page loads
        'duration': 0, // display duration
        'autoClose' : false, // flag to autoClose notification message
        'type' : 'success', // type of info message error/success/info/warning
        'message': '', // message to dispaly
        'link_notification' : '', // link flag to show extra description
        'description' : '' // link to desciption to display on clicking link message
    }; 
    // Extending array from params
    $.extend(true, options, params);

    var msgclass = 'succ_bg'; // default success message will shown
    if(options['type'] == 'error'){
        msgclass = 'error_bg'; // over write the message to error message
    } else if(options['type'] == 'information'){
        msgclass = 'info_bg'; // over write the message to information message
    } else if(options['type'] == 'warning'){
        msgclass = 'warn_bg'; // over write the message to warning message
    } 

    // Parent Div container
    var container = '<div id="info_message" class="'+msgclass+'"><div class="center_auto"><div class="info_message_text message_area">';
    container += options['message'];
    container += '</div><div class="info_close_btn button_area" onclick="return closeNotification()"></div><div class="clearboth"></div>';
    container += '</div><div class="info_more_descrption"></div></div>';

    $notification = $(container);

    // Appeding notification to Body
    $('body').append($notification);

    var divHeight = $('div#info_message').height();
    // see CSS top to minus of div height
    $('div#info_message').css({
        top : '-'+divHeight+'px'
    });

    // showing notification message, default it will be hidden
    $('div#info_message').show();

    // Slide Down notification message after startAfter seconds
    slideDownNotification(options['showAfter'], options['autoClose'],options['duration']);

    $('.link_notification').live('click', function(){
        $('.info_more_descrption').html(options['description']).slideDown('fast');
    });

}
// function to close notification message
// slideUp the message
function closeNotification(duration){
    var divHeight = $('div#info_message').height();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('div#info_message').animate({
            top: '-'+divHeight
        }); 
        // removing the notification from body
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('div#info_message').remove();
        },200);
    }, parseInt(duration * 1000));   



}

// sliding down the notification
function slideDownNotification(startAfter, autoClose, duration){    
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('div#info_message').animate({
            top: 0
        }); 
        if(autoClose){
            setTimeout(function(){
                closeNotification(duration);
            }, duration);
        }
    }, parseInt(startAfter * 1000));    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       showNotification({
            type : "success",
            message: "This is a sample success notification"
       }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Would it be hard to make the notification to push the content down?

Comment: No it's not.. But it would be better for you to ask/create a new question for that, as comments are not appropriate way for answers with large amount of code snippets...

Answer (score 0):

Using straight javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSuccessMessage(){
        showNotification({
            type : "success",
            message: "This is a sample success notification"
        });    
    } 

    window.onload = function() { 
        showSuccessMessage();
    }
</script>
```

Or jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSuccessMessage(){
        showNotification({
            type : "success",
            message: "This is a sample success notification"
        });    
    } 

    $(window).load(function(){
        showSuccessMessage();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Would it be hard to make the notification to push the content down?